# Request Only compressed data

Tags: php, guzzle

im trying to make a request in a remote xml file, and i receive a response from the server saying:

```
"Access denied, only compressed data can be send"
```

So i try using in my request:

```
$guzzleClient = new Client();
$feed_response = $guzzleClient->request('GET', $url,[
    'headers' => [
        'Accept-encoding: gzip'
    ],

    'debug' => true
]);
echo $feed_response->getStatusCode();
```

But it doesnt work, it gives me the same error, but if i use a example using curl:

```
curl -sH 'Accept-encoding: gzip' "domain/xmlfile" --compressed
```

It works fine, can someone tell me what is missing on the guzzle options?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was:

```
$feed_response = $guzzleClient->request('GET', $url,[

                    'headers'        => ['Accept-Encoding' => 'deflate, gzip'],


               // 'debug' => true
            ]);
```